# Dynamically add sequence numbers to labels

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML form which has text field with an add more button. When we click on the button a text field is added to the form. Following is the code for the form:

```
<div class="input-group g-mb-25">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <label class="input-group-text g-bg-white" for="fields[]">1.</label>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-md" placeholder="Enter your Video Title. This will also be the starting point of your video..." aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <!-- Checkbox -->
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-0">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="numCheck">
        <span class="custom-control-label">Show numbers</span>
    </label>
    <!-- End Checkbox -->
  </div>
</div>
<div class="entry input-group ">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <label class="input-group-text g-bg-white" for="inputGroupSelect01"></label>
  </div>
  <input class="form-control form-control-md" name="fields[]" type="text" placeholder="Type something" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" />
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-md u-btn-cyan rounded-0 btn-add" type="button">
        <span class="fa fa-plus align-middle mr-1"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The js for adding the fields is as follows:

```
// Add more fields
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var controlForm = $('.controls form:first'),
      currentEntry = $(this).parents('.entry:first'),
      newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);

    newEntry.find('input').val('');
    controlForm.find('.entry:not(:last) .btn-add')
      .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
      .removeClass('u-btn-cyan').addClass('u-btn-lightred')
      .html('<span class="fa fa-trash"></span>');
  }).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(e) {
    $(this).parents('.entry:first').remove();

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });
});
```

Notice that I have prepended a label to the text field:

```
<div class="input-group-prepend">
   <label class="input-group-text g-bg-white" for="fields[]"></label>
</div>
```

What I am unable to figure out is How can I add numbers to the label as I add more fields, 1 being the default number for the first Title field

Added form HTML with default field:

```
<div class="input-group g-mb-25">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <label class="input-group-text g-bg-white" for="fields[]"></label>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-md" placeholder="Enter your Video Title. This will also be the starting point of your video..." aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>

<div class="entry input-group ">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <label class="input-group-text g-bg-white" for="inputGroupSelect01"></label>
  </div>
  <input class="form-control form-control-md" name="fields[]" type="text" placeholder="Type something" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" />
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-md u-btn-cyan rounded-0 btn-add" type="button">
        <span class="fa fa-plus align-middle mr-1"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The new field is added as:

```
<div class="entry input-group ">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <label class="input-group-text g-bg-white" for="inputGroupSelect01"></label>
  </div>
  <input class="form-control form-control-md" name="fields[]" type="text" placeholder="Type something" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-md u-btn-cyan rounded-0 btn-add" type="button">
       <span class="fa fa-plus align-middle mr-1"></span>
   </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. Is the new field meant to go above or below the current field? 2. Can you show example HTML for the form with 1 label, and then when it has 2 labels?

Comment: The new field is added below the original field. Added the second point related html to the original answer.

Comment: You could make an increment logic based on the number of labels added. With the `^=` selector, you can find all the instances of a certain *name* attribute for instance. You can then use `.length` to the get the count. You can then do some conditioning based on that, assign a variable with the count, increment that upon adding new fields etc., and use that value as the numbers you wish to display in your label elements.